# Notification buttons issue - Android Studio

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-notifications, add-action

I'm trying to write code that, when a button in the notification (e.g., back button) is pressed, will be received in a receiver indicating that it was clicked. However, it's not working, and I don't know what to do. So far, I haven't focused on the back button, that's why I temporarily set the others to null. Once I figure out what I'm doing wrong with the back button, I'll easily handle the rest.

```
public class NotificationChannelBuilder {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel1";
    public static final int CHANNEL_ID_INT = 0;
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "MUSIC_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL";
    private static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "ACTION_PREVIOUS";
    
    Intent actionIntent;

    PendingIntent previousPendingIntent;

    public NotificationChannelBuilder(Context context) {
        actionIntent = new Intent(context, MusicNotification.class);
        actionIntent.setAction("ACTION_PREVIOUS");
        previousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, actionIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    public void showNotification(Context context, AudioModel song, int res) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_icon)
            .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_skip_previous_24, "Previous", previousPendingIntent )
            .addAction(res, "Play/Pause", null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_skip_next_24, "Next", null)
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
            .setContentTitle(song.getTitle())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSilent(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions.
            return;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(CHANNEL_ID_INT, builder.build());

    }
}


public class MusicNotification extends BroadcastReceiver implements  Observable {

    List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList();
    private String action = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String receivedAction = intent.getAction();

        if (receivedAction != null && receivedAction.equals("ACTION_PREVIOUS")) {
            action = "ACTION_PREVIOUS";
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cilcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if(receivedAction != null && receivedAction.equals("ACTION_NEXT"))
        {
            action = "ACTION_NEXT";
        }
        else if(receivedAction != null && receivedAction.equals("ACTION_PLAY/PAUSE"))
        {
            action = "ACTION_PLAY/PAUSE";
        }

        notifyObserver();
    }
....
the rest of the code
... 
}

public class MusicPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player);

        notificationChannelBuilder = new NotificationChannelBuilder(this);
...
       createNotificationChannel();
        notificationChannelBuilder.showNotification(this, songsList.get(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex), R.drawable.baseline_pause_circle_outline_24);
...
}

  private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is not in the Support Library.
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NotificationChannelBuilder.CHANNEL_ID, NotificationChannelBuilder.CHANNEL_NAME, importance);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MusicNotification"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_PREVIOUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Logs:
Expecting binder but got null!
2024-01-20 14:24:27.007   834-1058  EGL_emulation           com.android.systemui                 D  app_time_stats: avg=98.50ms min=3.05ms max=1948.32ms count=21
2024-01-20 14:24:27.238   626-646   CoreBackPreview         system_server                        D  Window{e75868 u0 Toast}: Setting back callback null
2024-01-20 14:24:27.241   626-646   InputManager-JNI        system_server                        W  Input channel object 'e75868 Toast (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
2024-01-20 14:24:27.244   626-646   NotificationService     system_server                        W  Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.musicplayer token=android.os.BinderProxy@abacc80
2024-01-20 14:24:27.245   834-834   ToastPresenter          com.android.systemui                 W  Error calling back com.example.musicplayer to notify onToastHide()
                                                                                                    android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ITransientNotificationCallback$Stub$Proxy.onToastHidden(ITransientNotificationCallback.java:141)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.ToastPresenter.hide(ToastPresenter.java:283)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI$ToastOutAnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(ToastUI.java:4)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:600)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.AnimatorSet.endAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1301)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1086)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:307)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-$$Nest$mdoAnimationFrame(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:86)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1229)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:827)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

What should I fix to make the previous buttons work?